# Given a mean, standard deviation and proportion can we determine if it is a normal distribution?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

Given just a mean and standard deviation and proportion of the data that is over X can we determine if it is a normal distribution? I want to say no, because even if the we take X - mean / SD and take that Z-score and use it to find the proportion, even if that proportion is equal to the proportion given, I don't think that is still enough information to determine if it's a normal distribution because we don't know how the data below X is distributed. But I could be missing something?

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: A more specific example would give us enough information to give you a specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

Say you were given $E(X)=0$, $\text{Var}(X)=1$ and $P(X\ge0)=0.5$. Then you cannot just assume that $X\sim N(0,1)$ because any symmetrical distribution with variance $1$ satisfies these conditions. For example the uniform continuous distribution - $X\sim\text{unif}(-\sqrt{3},\sqrt{3})$ - is such a distribution.

Comment: Say my example is only true for a sample. What reason could we say that even given this information for a sample that the distribution of the population is NOT normally distributed?

Comment: Why does using sample data make any difference? There are infinitely many population distributions that could allow for any given sample distribution.

Comment: Is there some sort of theorem or axiom that I can use to show that? It does make sense, but I feel like I need something more concrete.